# Multiple stage sizes in Actionscript 3/Flash CS5

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5, stage

I'm building a downloadable flash app that appears as a window on a computer rather than a window in a browser.  However, certain parts of the program will play YouTube videos, still within the program, not in a browser.  That part is working fine.

However, I would like to change the size of the stage when it is running a Youtube video.  Is that possible, or do I have to have the same size window showing for everything?

Comment: I'm not using AIR.  I'm not trying to get the youtube fullscreen option working, I want the actual window that has the youtube video and some other buttons to be bigger than the normal window that I'm using for the other scenes.

Comment: What platform are you using then?  flash projector?  Zinc?

Comment: I'm using the CS5 Flash Professional development platform- not sure if I understand your question.

Comment: Right now I'm just running it as Publish Preview Flash.

Comment: Well, at any rate, you can't adjust window size unless you're using AIR or some other advanced container like MDM Zinc.

Comment: OK, I'll check out AIR.

Comment: Much as I appreciate the link given with "this question already has an answer here:", that answer does not apply to my question.  I am not using HTML, this is an app running on a machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the size of the stage by accessing the Document's Class, like this: `this.width` and `this.height`

UPDATE

It turns out only the embedding application can change the state, and changing the size through actionscript will not work, so throughout the player you'd have to probably access the `NativeApplication` through adobe air as you can see here: http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=222865 and as you can see here: http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=242042 - this shows you can only set the stage size during compile time.

Comment: That does not work.  Remember, I'm trying to change the size of the document for one scene, not for all scenes, and setting this.height/width does not affect the size of the program window that comes up.

Comment: @user792826 It should change the size of the document class, so try an update function.  UPDATE (in answer edit)